# Unable to install Cobertura plugin in Jenkins

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, jestjs, jenkins-plugins, cobertura

In my Jenkins 2.277.4, when I try to install Cobertura plugin in Jenkins, it gives me below error :

```
Cobertura Failure -
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: Jenkins Cobertura Plugin (1.16)
 - Failed to load: Code Coverage API Plugin (1.4.0)
    at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:950)
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:930)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to install cobertura plugin
    at hudson.PluginManager.dynamicLoad(PluginManager.java:943)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2174)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to dynamically deploy this plugin
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2178)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1844)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:118)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My aim is to show Code Coverage in Jenkins for my react application (I am using jest for react application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were couple of things that I tried :

- Updated the dependencies related to Cobertura
- Restart the jenkins server